# Getting the orchestration parent name or id in the calling orchestration

Tags: biztalk, orchestration, biztalk-orchestrations, biztalk-2013r2

I have an orchestration that calls another orchestration.

Is it possible to get the orchestration name or id of the parent in the calling orchestration in an Expression shape?

Comment: Why not pass that as a parameter from the calling orchestration to the called orchestration?

Comment: Yes, i can do that.. but I just want to know if it is possible to get this information without passing a parameter or variable, but just getting it from the system?

Comment: Any reason why you want to do it that way?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box is not possible, so you would need to pass it as a parameter from your calling orchestration.

There is the option to pick up the name of the orchestration like so: `Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Service.RootService.Name`. 
However, when calling an orchestration and using this method, you will get the name of the CALLING orchestration in your CALLED orchestration.

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass an identifier for the caller as a Parameter.